# vitest mount does not render template

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vitest

I'm working on a vue component that I'm fitting a leaflet map into.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import leaflet from "leaflet"

let map
onMounted(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector("#map"))
    
    map = leaflet.map('map').setView([38.582958, -90.289045], 15);
    leaflet.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    leaflet.marker([38.582958, -90.289045]).addTo(map)
})


</script>

<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>
```

*the component with everything but the map stuff ripped out*

This setup works fine when loaded into the browser:
[image: map rendering fine in the browser]

But when I try to run any of my tests I get an error that the map container (the dom element leaflet is trying to attach to) cannot be found:
[image: element cannot be found]

And this is happening on tests that I've already built out while TDD-ing out other elements of the component and I know work fine pre-map addition.

I'm looking through the vue testing utility docs and it seems like [mounting the component in the test should render the component](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount), so I'm not sure why the dom elements aren't rendering.

Is there a way of properly mounting the component so the dom element can render, or is there a different way I should be writing my component code to support the map attaching to the element during testing??

## Update

After Estus' comment about mocking leaflet (:facepalm:) I went through and stubbed out the leaflet touch points:

[image]

And my existing tests pass.

I'm not sure if this is the most succinct way of stubbing a module out on the front end (all of my testing experience is in backend frameworks in different languages), but this at least gets me going. Thanks!!

Comment: You need to mock third-party libs in unit tests, especially ones that depend on dom and cannot work correctly in non-browser environment

Comment: oh! duh! I don't know why I wasn't thinking of leaflet as an external collaborator that needed to be at least stubbed :/ Thanks!